# Will php stop supporting apache in the windows binaries?

Tags: php, windows, apache

I noticed in the latest 5.3.13 release that there is no binary for windows running apache. Its all IIS. They only have binary for 5.2 running apache.

http://windows.php.net/download/

Will future Windows binaries be all IIS only?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see there, you just can't use it with the binaries from apache.org. VC9 supports the binaries from [Apachelounge](http://www.apachelounge.com).

Comment: I guess that will have to do.